# Updating entity name in redis upon updating Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, redis, eloquent

A lot of models in my application have names and I store them in redis eg. device:1:name

Wight now I'm refreshing it every hour, but I would like to do it only when model updates (on create, update whatever)

What's the easiest way to do so?

Comment: overload your model default methods `save()` and `create()`. `Insert()`and `update()` too if you're willing to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events). Just set the property `$dispatchesEvents` in your `Device` model with key-value peers specifies the `Event` class for the events you want to dispatch.

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'saved' => DeviceSaved::class,
    'updated' => DeviceUpdated::class,
];
```

You can learn more about writing `Event` classes [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events).